# German potato salad tofurkey bacon usage?

Tags: substitutes, lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, recipe-request

I’m mostly curious about this. Is it possible to use tofurkey bacon on place of regular bacon in German potato salad? If not could you please give me a good vegetarian version of German potato salad please.
I thought that this list would be a good place to find out for sure.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a vegan version (egg-free, dairy-free) or are you okay with lacto-ovo vegetarian? Knowing this would be useful for providing product recommendations.

Comment: I’m ok with lacto-ovo @Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? Compared to traditional American potato salad, authentic German potato salad is different because it uses vinegar instead of mayonnaise (eggs), and bacon rather than eggs. Some potato salad purists might think a recipe without pig fat is not authentic, but being "authentic" is not necessary to make a delicious dish.

So I guess your question is which non-meat bacon substitute would work best for this salad.

I don't think [Tofurky Smoky Maple Bacon](https://tofurky.com/what-we-make/tempeh/smoky-maple-bacon/) is going to be the best choice here. It's really more of a smoky-flavoured tempeh strip, and won't have quite the right textural appeal for use in salad.

Might be better to try something like Lightlife Smart Bacon (soy protein isolate and wheat gluten) or [Sweet Earth Benevolent Bacon](https://store.veganessentials.com/benevolent-bacon-hickory--sage-smoked-seitan-bacon-by-sweet-earth-p4325.aspx) if you can find them. If you can't find those products, you might want to try a homemade meatless bacon recipe like [this one from No Meat Athlete](https://www.nomeatathlete.com/vegan-bacon/).